# How to make an object look at the camera using displacement

Tags: displacement

How can I use material displacement to make an object always look at the camera? I've been blindly following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRjeQSThXkk) to rotate it around the z-axis, but I would like rotate it around every axis.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this with shader-displacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector transform from camera to world should work:

[image]

Additional vector rotate is to make Z facing up (Camera's Z axis pointing backwards).

Subtract is used to remove original coordinates, it is quite common.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Do you perhaps have a link to a website for in-depth explanation of vector nodes?

Comment: @NeilGiliomee nope